# iOS8.0.2 CLLocationManager stopped working, kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined

Tags: ios, ios8, cllocationmanager

I started developing app couple month ago (ios7), got location manager working as needed.

Now with xCode6/iOS8 it quit. Here is what I see.

App starts, location manager starts and I get status "NotDetermined". Uninstalling app doesn't force popup or anything like this. I go to setting, choose to "Always" allow, setting shows "Always". Start my app, same problem. Got to setting - tit shows blank again.

Is that a known issue with iOS8? What else I can try?

Comment: I noticed the same issue.  Haven't figured it out yet :(

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. iOS8 brought some changes. Now we (developers) should ask user for permission in case it's "NotDetermined".. `requestAlwaysAuthorization`
Also, new .plist entry required

> When the current authorization status is
>   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined, this method runs asynchronously
>   and prompts the user to grant permission to the app to use location
>   services. The user prompt contains the text from the
>   NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file,
>   **and the presence of that key is required when calling this method**.
>   After the status is determined, the location manager delivers the
>   results to the delegate’s
>   locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus: method.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager

Comment: There is also `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key if you don't wanna use location services while app is in background. Once determined, allowance alert is not shown anymore and you should direct the user to go to the settings app and enable what's needed there. Have a look at [the following NSHipster link](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/) under **Requesting Multiple Permissionsthis** to see how to direct the user directly to your app's setup.